# Chrome Postman REST: reusing response values as request params in collections?

Tags: rest, postman

I'm playing around with [Postman REST extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm)'s collections feature.

I have 2 requests: the 1st returns a sessionId in its response body and the  2nd requires the `{{sessionId}}` value as query param. Can I tell Postman to save the body of the 1st response to the `{{sessionId}}` variable?

I currently have to a) execute 1st request and b) copy response body and paste it as a value of the 2nd request's query param every time...

thanks,
-nikita

Comment: I use Postman quite a bit, but as far as I know, it doesn't have that capability.  It would be an interesting enhancement, though.

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely Yes!
Here is a json example:
I added the following to the Tests Tab of the first request:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);

postman.setGlobalVariable("session_id", data['session_id']);
```

Basically retrieving the data from responseBody and set it as a global variable

Then in the second request, the URL would be something like this:

```
http://{{whateverhost}}/api/v1/somefunction/{{session_id}}
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers

Comment: Note that Postman also supports a dot notation, such as `postman.setEnvironmentVariable("sessionId", data.session_id);`